# iPhone application installation

Tags: iphone

i am not a member of iPhone developer, i installed one iPhoneOS 2.2 in my computer, and i developed one application. and i created it as a .ipa file and i installed my iPhone but it is not working.

i am sure i am not a iPhone developer, not register in iPhone developer.

is it that problems.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to officially install applications on the iPhone that you have developed, you need to be part of the iPhone Developer program which costs $99/year.

Without the certificates and provisioning profiles you get by being part of the program, you cannot officially push software to device or submit your software to Apple to be in the App Store.

You can test the applications within the iPhone Simulator without being part of the program.

Other options all include Jailbreaking the iPhone - which I don't know anything about and cannot help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you have to register with the iPhone developer program (and pay $99) in order to be able to sign the app and run it on your iPhone.